# RDFox access view

Tags: sparql, datalog, rdfox

Can I set view only access to the knowledge graph using RDFox Version 3? (No editing)

I would like to create different user roles and control who can see/edit what right down to the triple level.

Comment: docs: https://oxfordsemtech.github.io/RDFoxDocs/_versions/3.0.1/#/06-access-control?id=access-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the access control feature you can assign roles and grant privileges to users, for example you could limit a users privileges to view only.

For example, you can use the **role** command and **create** subcommand to create a new user:

```
role create user1
Enter the password for the new role:
Confirm the password:    
A new role was created with name "user1".    
role create group   
Enter the password for the new role:    
Confirm the password:    
A new role was created with name "group”.
```

Then you can **grant** privileges, for example:

```
> grant privileges read,write,grant >datastores|* to user1    
The privileges 'read,write,grant' over resource specifier ">datastores|*" were granted to the role "user1" (if not already present).
```

Or you can **revoke** privileges, for example:

```
> revoke privileges write,grant >datastores|* from user1    
The privileges 'write,grant' over resource specifier ">datastores|*" were revoked from the role "user1" (if they were present).
```

If you then use the **show** subcommand you can see what **role** and privileges the user has:

```
> role show user1

'user1' has the following directly assigned privileges:

  Resource specifier |  Allowed access types   

  >datastores|*      |  read
```

This has resulted in a read only privilege for the user.

Comment: a link to the [docs](https://oxfordsemtech.github.io/RDFoxDocs/_versions/3.0.1/#/06-access-control?id=access-control) would have been sufficient I guess, but anyways  a good concise answer.  Maybe you guys could also extend the docs with those more specific use-cases examples if possible?